# Python 3: Met "ndarray is not contiguous" when construct a regression function

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array, linear-regression, contiguous

This code is designed for calculating a linear regression by defining a function "standRegres" which compile by ourself. Although we can do the lm by the functions in sklearn or statsmodels, here we just try to construct the function by ourself. But unfortunately, I confront error and can't conquer it. So, I'm here asking for your favor to help.

The whole code runs without any problem until the last row. If I run the last row, an Error message emerges: "ValueError: ndarray is not contiguous".

```
import os

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
# load data
iris = load_iris()
# Define a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns = iris.feature_names)
# take a look
df.head()
#len(df)


# rename the column name 
df.columns = ['sepal_length','sepal_width','petal_length','petal_width']


X = df[['petal_length']]
y = df['petal_width']


from numpy import *
#########################
# Define function to do matrix calculation
def standRegres(xArr,yArr):
    xMat = mat(xArr); yMat = mat(yArr).T
    xTx = xMat.T * xMat
    if linalg.det(xTx) == 0.0:
        print ("this matrix is singular, cannot do inverse!")
        return NA
    else :
        ws = xTx.I * (xMat.T * yMat)
        return ws

# test
x0 = np.ones((150,1))
x0 = pd.DataFrame(x0)
X0 = pd.concat([x0,X],axis  = 1)

# test
standRegres(X0,y)
```

This code runs without any problem until the last row. If I run the last row, an Error message emerges: "ValueError: ndarray is not contiguous".

I dry to solve it but don't know how. Could you help me? Quite appreciate for that!

Comment: Does it say "C-contiguous", or does it say "Fortran-contiguous"?

Comment: @aryamccarthy  It just say "not contiguous". I don't know why it didn't say whether C or Fortran. And I also see some guys were asking questions when the met the problem with "not C-contiguous" in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem stems from using the `mat` function. Stick to `array`.

In order to use `array`, you'll need to use the `@` sign for matrix multiplication, not `*`. Finally, you have a line that says `xTx.I`, but that function isn't defined for general arrays, so we can use `numpy.linalg.inv`.

```
def standRegres(xArr,yArr):
    xMat = array(xArr); yMat = array(yArr).T
    xTx = xMat.T @ xMat
    if linalg.det(xTx) == 0.0:
        print ("this matrix is singular, cannot do inverse!")
        return NA
    else :
        ws = linalg.inv(xTx) @ (xMat.T @ yMat)
        return ws

# test
x0 = np.ones((150,1))
x0 = pd.DataFrame(x0)
X0 = pd.concat([x0,X],axis  = 1)

# test
standRegres(X0,y)
# Output: array([-0.36651405,  0.41641913])
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much. I think I start to know how to use     @     ,
    array      and    numpy.linalg.inv     now.  And sorry I don't have the right to upvote your answer because my reputation is lower than 15, but I appreciate your help. And, could I ask one more question -- if I want to get the result of this regression as a matrix, like "matrix([[-0.36651405], [ 0.41641913]])", what should I do? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, when I upvote, it said "votes cast by those with less than 15 reputations are recorded, but do not change the public displayed post score "

Comment: Don't worry, man. My reputation now is 8. If I ask one more question and receive one more answer, then I can vote. I promise I'll back and upvote your answer. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you. And if I want the result of this regression to be a matrix, like "matrix([[-0.36651405], [ 0.41641913]])", what should I do? So many thanks!

Comment: Don't bother making it a matrix. Use [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html). If you need more details about this, ask them in a separate question.

Comment: Hi, bro. I start up a new question to go further on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070352/python3-how-to-let-the-result-of-this-regression-to-be-a-matrix